# Почему не предзакачивается видео?

Tags: клиент-сервер, настройка

Ещё год назад можно было открыть видео, нажать на паузу, подождать 15 минут часик пока оно закачается, а потом нормально смотреть. Сейчас и в хроме, и в фоксе возможность предзагрузки пропала, в том числе для ютуба. С чем это связано? Как можно активировать этот функционал? Возможно в `about:config` нужно что-то подправить? Или это какие-то негласные запреты?

Comment: Ну, с тем, что браузер не в курсе, что вы собрались смотреть целиком и считает что чего зря трафик тратить?

Comment: @andreymal это спорный вопрос. Я рекламу не хочу смотреть - реклама показывается в полном обьеме и отлично. Я уже разобрался как и в каком виде видеопоток попадает в браузер. Но всё же - функция предзакачки была? Да. Её по какой-то причине выключили? Значит ответа на вопрос два 1) из-за таких-то причин функция больше не доступна и никогда доступна не будет (со ссылкой на источник). Нарушать эти правила можно(написав плагин/примочку)/нельзя потому что.  2)Функция отключена но включить её можно зайдя в меню, в нем десять раз перейти на пункт х, поставить галочку, или к-во предзакачиваемых байт.

Comment: Меня тоже вопрос интерисует. В Firefox, кстати в about:config, нашёл параметр network.preload (до этого, существовал autobuffer, но, было это, мягко говоря, довольно таки давно), по дефолту он теперь false.

Comment: @test123 я тоже на этот признак подумал. Когда  `network.preload=true` то браузер отображает предзагрузку (после рестарта), но грузит только если состояние play. Наверно где-то ещё что-то нужно включить.